# SharePoint 2010 VS Workflow Upgrade

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-workflow

I feel this is probably a common task but I'm struggling with it.  I have developed a custom workflow with VS 2010 and have deloped it.  This workflow is attached to many lists.  I would now like to make a change to this workflow (add some activities).  How can I deploy this workflow without having to readd this workflow to all the lists that already have this workflow attached to it.  It is not necessary to version this workflow.  I just need all items added to the lists that already had this workflow attached to pick up these changes.

Any help appreciated!  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Its always a good practise to version the workflow. You just have to copy the new version in your GAC and update the version number in your workflow.xml file.

If you dont want versioning, then cancel all workflows that were running before you made changes to the workflow code(otherwise it will throw an error).Now replace the dll in GAC with the new workflow dll.

Thanks!